# Как обойти ошибку при сборке из исходников?

Tags: gcc, lua, cmake, сборка

Требуется: установить Яндекс.Томиту
https://github.com/yandex/tomita-parser/

cmake, lua, gcc - всё самых последних на сегодняшний день версий, устанавливал всё через brew.
Компилю: `../src/ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` - выбвает ошибку:

`tools.cmake: libsupc++.a/libsupc++.a doesn't exist (with positive USE_STATIC_CPP_RUNTIME)`

Вопрос: что это за ошибка и как её обойти?
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Пальцем в небо: выключить `USE_STATIC_CPP_RUNTIME` в CMake?

Comment: @arrowd Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос: как это можно сделать? (Со сборкой из исходников никогда ранее не сталкивался)

Comment: `cmake -DUSE_STATIC_CPP_RUNTIME=0 .` в папке `build`.

Comment: @arrowd к сожалению, безрезультатно :(

Comment: Посмотрел их код, что-то там странно. Попробуйте в local.cmake вставить `set(USE_STATIC_CPP_RUNTIME no)`.

Comment: @arrowd Поменял, всё равно не работает. Подсказали, что ошибка в gcc: сейчас там стоит более ранняя версия по умолчанию, чем та, которая требуется. Новый gcc тоже установлен, но пока не знаю, как поменять версию со старой на новую

Comment: `cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=... -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=... .`

Comment: *Новый gcc тоже установлен, но пока не знаю, как поменять версию со старой на новую*. зачем менять? просто укажите использовать нужный вам компилятор, как и полагается, переменной окружения: `CXX=имя-или-путь-к-файлу`

Comment: Поменял, ошибка та же. Попробую cmake даунгрейдить